# Checking if an image is cut from another image

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I have two images: image 1 and image 2, image 1 is smaller than image 2. I want to check that whether image 1 is cut from image 2 or not. To be precisely, I'm using python.

The idea I'm thinking of is that I'm gonna put the image 1 inside the image 2 and sliding it all over image 2 until all the pixels of image 1 matching a certain region in image 2. I could have a naive implementation for this idea by using multiple loops, but it is quite slow.

How can I do it faster ? Could it be done by using function in some package ?

Comment: You could try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31874879/2836621

Comment: You can use a pyramidal approach to speed-up the search.

Comment: Sounds like [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)...