# how to search an image for subimages on linux

Tags: imagemagick

i've seen the answer of Mark Setchell (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell), which seems to be outdated and not working anymore. [How to search an image for subimages using linux console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867093/how-to-search-an-image-for-subimages-using-linux-console)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31874879/17686212
[How to search an image for subimages using linux console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867093/how-to-search-an-image-for-subimages-using-linux-console)

downloading the needle and creating the haystack image and "hiding" the needles within it works fine.
[Needle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jz2c.png)

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient:lime-blue haystack.png
convert haystack.png needle.png -geometry +30+5 -composite haystack.png 
convert haystack.png needle.png -geometry +100+150 -composite haystack.png
```

Running the specified compare Images command causes an error:

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search haystack.png needle.png locations.png
compare: images too dissimilar `haystack.png' @ error/compare.c/CompareImagesCommand/1166.
```

i've tried to apply -similarity-threshold and -dissimilarity-threshold and changed/lowered the convert location threshold but had no success aka bad results like this:

```
compare -similarity-threshold 0 -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -metric RMSE -subimage-search haystack.png needle.png locations.png
convert locations-1.png -threshold 95% txt: | grep white
```

[locations-0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m1Zy.png)
[locations-1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxnwE.png)

I've used imagemagick version 7.1.0.14 on gentoo and 6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3 on kali Linux

Hopefully you can help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If using IM 7, then use `magick compare` not `compare`

Comment: With IM 7, you can do masked compare, if you create a mask for your needle image so that the large amount of white does not mismatch with the green and blue of the haystack image. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=31053

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do masked composite in ImageMagick 7.

Template:

[image]

Image:

[image]

Create Mask:

```
magick needle.png -transparent white -alpha extract mask.png
```

[image]

```
magick compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 haystack.png \( -read-mask mask.png needle.png \) compare.png
```

```
9031.97 (0.137819) @ 100,150
```

Compare-0 (differences):

[image]

Compare-1 (match scores):

[image]

If you want to find the best matches, you would need to use my script, [maxima](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/maxima/index.php)

```
maxima -t 80 -n 10 compare-1.png
```

```
max=1 100,150 gray=56540,220,86.2745%
max=2 30,5 gray=54484,212,83.137%
```

You will not get a good result from ImageMagick 6 with

```
compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 haystack.png needle.png compare.png

26789 (0.408773) @ 96,114
```

because there is too much white in your needle image and it will mismatch with the green and blue in the haystack image. Unfortunately, you cannot do masked compare in ImageMagick 6.